# I am load Html String into webview but i want to disable image click but image should redirect to fullscreen image activity?

Tags: android

I m trying this code but the image also loads in webview on click.

public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Bind(R.id.webView)
WebView webView;
private String iteamRichText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    final Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    iteamRichText = mIntent.getExtras().getString(getResources().getString(R.string.putkey_iteam_richText));
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

   // webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   // webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    webView.setFocusable(false);
    webView.loadData(iteamRichText, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //view.loadData(iteamRichText, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        Log.e("process", "" + url);

        if(url.startsWith("http") && (url.contains(".jpg") || url.contains(".png") || url.contains(".jpeg") || url.contains(".gif")))
        {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, FullScreenImgActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.putkey_webViewfullImagePath), url);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(url.startsWith("http") && (url.contains(".jpg") || url.contains(".png") || url.contains(".jpeg") || url.contains(".gif")))
            {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, FullScreenImgActivity.class);
                mIntent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.putkey_webViewfullImagePath), url);
                mIntent.putExtra("IMAGE_URL",url);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
```

FullScreenImgActivity

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_URL")));
```